# Creating Quartz Scheduler instances at run time

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am working on an application where we have 100 of jobs that's needs to be schedules for executions.
Here is my sample quartz.property file

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=QuartzScheduler
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=7
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.MSSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quartz
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user=root
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password=root
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections=5
```

Though this is working fine, but we are planning to separates jobs in different groups so that it can be easy to maintain them.
Groups will be unique and we want that if a user(Admin) creates a new group a new instance of scheduler should get created and all jobs within that group should be handled  by that scheduler instance in future.
This means if the Admin creates a new group say *NewProductNotification* than we should be able to create a scheduler instance with same name *NewProductNotification* and all jobs which are parts of the *NewProductNotification* group should be handeled by *NewProductNotification* instance of scheduler.

How is this possible and how can we store this information in the Database so that next time when the server is up Quartz should have knowledge about all the scheduler instances or do we need to add this information about new instance in property file.

As the proprty file above showing , we are using `jdbcjobstore` to handle everything using database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think dynamically creating schedulers is a good desing approach in Quartz. You can share the same database tables for multiple schedulers (job details and triggers have scheduler name as part of their primary key) but `Scheduler` is kind of heavyweight.

Can you explain why do you relly need separate schedulers? Maybe you can simply use Job groups and triggers groups (you are in fact using the term *group*) to distinguish jobs/groups? Also you can use different priorities for each trigger.

## As a side note:

> ### I'm using JobStoreCMT and I'm seeing deadlocks, what can I do?
>
> Make sure you have at least number-of-threads-in-thread-pool + 2 connections in your datasources.

And in your configuration (reverse the values and it will be fine):

```
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=7
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections=5
```

From: [I'm using JobStoreCMT and I'm seeing deadlocks, what can I do?](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/faq#FAQ-cmtDead)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, idea was to create groups and create a same scheduler so that each instance can have less load.Do you think a single instance of scheduler will be enough to execute 100's of jobs per day?

Comment: @user702325: `Scheduler` is not a bottle-neck here, it is a databse and worker threads. 100's of jobs per day is not much. 100's of jobs concurrently is. But in this case consider clustering a single scheduler rather than starting multiple ones (which will only affect performance in a negative way).

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically creating schedules is very much possible. You would need to create objects of JobDetail and Trigger and pass to the SchedulerFactoryBean object. It will take care of the rest.

Comment: can you provide some kind of example or a link and i am using simple Quartz scheduler and not spring to handle this

Comment: sorry i misinterpreted your question. it is not recommended to start multiple schedulers on the same database where there is already another scheduler running. refer to http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/cookbook/MultipleSchedulers